# javascript file upload trouble using FormData, recive empty $_FILES

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I created a simple file upload to my server using JavaScript.
And it works, but with some jpeg/png files I receive empty `$_FILES` and `$_POST` vars.
I tried a lot of ways, but have not found a solution.

My HTML is something like this:

```
<input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" multiple="true" onchange="upload(this.files,0);">
```

JS function:

```
    upload = function(files,aid){
    $.each(files,function(i,file){
        if(file.type.match(/image.jpeg/) || file.type.match(/image.png/) ){
            if(file.size < 10*1024*1024){
            var intreval = setInterval(function(){
                    if(xhrCheck == false){
                        xhrCheck = true;
                        var formData = new FormData();
                        formData.append("file",file);
                        formData.append("aid",aid);
                        function success(data){console.log("success!");};

                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $.ajax({
                                xhr: function() {
                                    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                                    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                                        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                            var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                                            percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
                                            console.log(percentComplete);
                                            if (percentComplete === 100) {
                                                xhrCheck = false;
                                                clearInterval(intreval);
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }, false);

                                    return xhr;
                                },
                                type : "POST",
                                url : "/photo_uploader.php",
                                data : formData,
                                dataType : "JSON",
                                cache: false,
                                contentType: false,
                                processData: false,
                                success : success,
                            })

                        },1000);
                    }
                },1);
            }
            else {
                alert("more than 10mb!");
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("only JPEG or PNG allowed!");
        }
    });
};
```

In PHP I just simple show `$_POST` and `$_FILES` vars like this:

```
pinrt_r($_FILES);
print_r($_POST);
```

In normal way, a receive something like this:

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => _DSC0004.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phppUJNS5
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 5185226
        )

)
Array
(
    [aid] => 0
)
```

But when I chose some other pics (not all!) I receive this:

```
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
```

But if I modify this image (like resize), it normally uploads to server.

I tried use `XMLHttpRequest`
and replace Ajax request to this:

```
var xmlRq = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xmlRq.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total; percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
        console.log(percentComplete);
          if (percentComplete === 100) {
                xhrCheck = false;
                clearInterval(intreval);
            }

        }
    }, false);

    xmlRq.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
           if(this.status == 200) {
            console.log(this.response);
            }
          }
    };
    xmlRq.open('POST', '/photo_uploader.php');
    console.log(formData.getAll('file'));
    xmlRq.send(formData);
```

With this code i have the same problem.

In FireBug i can see POST data, it's always have data to send.

I can't understand why sometimes i receive empty `$_FILES` and `$_POST` and where my mistake.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Escape meta chars in regex => `/image\.jpeg/`

Comment: @lshettyl  I don't totally understand what you recommended me. Can explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to increase upload_max_filesize and post_max_size.
you can change these values from php.ini file.

Comment: Thanks! This resolve my problem. I completly forgot about php.ini =\